# Array of actual Classes

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

```
  Ship *ship;

  if (newShipType == 0)
  {
    ship = new SmallShip(gridPosition.x, gridPosition.y,
                         grid->raw);
  }
  else if (newShipType == 1)
  {
    ship = new MediumShip(gridPosition.x, gridPosition.y,
                          grid->raw);
  }
  else // 2
  {
    ship = new BigShip(gridPosition.x, gridPosition.y,
                       grid->raw);
  }
```

I have that code I want to simplify with something along the lines of:

```
Ship *ship = new getShipByType[newShipType](gridPosition.x, gridPosition.y, grid->raw);
```

Is something like that possible?

```
Ship getShipByType[3] = {SmallShip, MediumShip, BigShip};
```

That gives:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
```

I didn't really expect it to compile, just looking for a simpler way of doing this and it was just a very long shot attempt.

Comment: Read up on the "factory pattern". It might help you.

Comment: Surely OP should read up on "shipyard pattern" ?

Comment: In short; no. But as arne said you should look into the factory pattern.

Comment: +1 just for having used "classes" correctly and not meaning "objects".

Comment: @DanielDaranas Whats so special about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to implement a factory for Ship creation, something like this:

```
enum ShipSize { Small, Medium, Big};

class ShipFactory
{
public:
    // consider return std::unique_ptr, shared_ptr or std::auto_ptr
    Ship * createShip(ShipSize size)
    {
        switch (size)
        {
            case Small: return new SmallShip();
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

To automate memory management you could also consider returning std::unique_ptr (if you use new compiler, or shared_ptr, or auto_ptr if you have old one).

Answer (score 5):

You could delegate a function to create different ships, it's normally known as factory pattern. Also array doesn't deal with polymorphism, you need to use vector instead:

```
#include <memory>

enum ShipType { Small = 0, Medium, Big };

std::unique_ptr<Ship> makeShip(ShipType ship_type, GridPosition position)
{
  switch(ship_type)
  {
    case Small:
      return std::unique_ptr<Ship>(new SmallShip());
    break;
    case Medium:
      return std::unique_ptr<Ship>(new MediumShip());
    case Big
      return std::unique_ptr<Ship>(new BigShip());
    default:
      break;
  } 
  return nullptr;
}

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ship>> ships;
ships.push_back(makeShip(Samll));
ships.push_back(makeShip(Medium));
ships.push_back(makeShip(Big));
// now fly your ship!!!
```

Comment: @Paranaix yes, and I want make_unique as well, however, make_unique is not available in C++11, that's why I simple return raw pointer to make return look simpler :)

Comment: But im pretty sure that the above code wont compile and the lack of `make_unique` isnt a problem either as a `std::unqiue_ptr` is implecitely constructable from `T*`

Answer (score 3):

You could use an array of function pointers.

Adding a static template function to Ship will allow it to serve as the factory.

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Ship> (*fnShipCreate)(int,int,void*);
template <class T> static std::unique_ptr<Ship> create(int x, int y, void* raw) { return new T(x, y, raw); }
```

(Note that you did not specify the types of your constructor parameters, so I made a reasonable guess...)

This allows the array of function pointers to be specified as follows, creating an instance of the template function for each type of ship:

```
Ship::fnShipCreate shipCreators[] = { Ship::create<SmallShip>, 
                                      Ship::create<MediumShip>, 
                                      Ship::create<BigShip> };
```

and it could be called using (assuming the variable names in the original post):

```
std::unique_ptr<Ship> ship = shipCreators[newShipType](gridPosition.x, gridPosition.y, grid->raw);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `SmallShip`, `MediumShip` and `BigShip` are different derived classes from `Ship`, you can't store the instance in a `Ship` variable. It HAS to be a reference or a pointer.

As mentioned in the comment, a factory function is definitely a possible solution (but then, aside from the hard-coded numbers for type that should be an enum in my book, it's pretty much what your first code-section is).